# How Enable and disable line of code according to current screens or State?

Tags: java, eclipse, graphics2d

I have three screens in my game: Help, Menu, and the game itself.

There are two buttons in the Menu state which work fine until the help button is pressed. After pressing the help button and going to the help screen, the back button that is supposed to show the menu screen doesn't work.

I found that commenting out `handler.getMouseManager().setUIManger(uiManager);` makes the button work as intended.

How do I make this line **only** work if I am on the menu screen?

**Menu State(Screen Script)**

```
public MenuState(Handler handler) {

    super(handler);

    uiManager = new UIManager(handler);

    handler.getMouseManager().setUIManger(uiManager);

    uiManager.addObject(new UIImageButton(250, 200, 168, 64, assets.btn_start, new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick() {

            handler.getMouseManager().setUIManger(null);
            State.setState(handler.getGame().gameState);

        }

    }));

    uiManager.addObject(new UIImageButton(250, 270, 168, 64, assets.btn_help, new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick() {

            handler.getMouseManager().setUIManger(null);

            State.setState(handler.getGame().helpState);

        }
    }));
}

@Override
public void tick() {

    uiManager.tick();

    System.out.println(State.getState());

}

@Override
public void render(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 700);

    uiManager.render(g);

}
```

}